# connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :

Tags: kubernetes

I am running Mongodb pod in kunernetes cluster using nfs volume.I am writing pod.yml like this

[image]

but i am getting the below error[image]

Could anybody suggest how to resolve the above issue?

Comment: Please put both your configuration and the error message as text in your question instead of images for obvious reasons of readability and searchability.

Comment: Spelling / typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am running Mongodb pod in kunernetes cluster using nfs volume.I am writing pod.yml like this

Putting `mongo` in the `command:` is erroneous. The **daemon** is `mongod` and the image [would have started it automatically](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/27496625/4.0/Dockerfile#L91) had you not provided any `command:` at all.

Further, all `command:` lines are `exec`-ed, so putting `bash -c` in front of a command is just moving that command out of pid 1 and unnecessarily adding memory consumption to your container.

Comment: Thanks for responding my Question Matthew L Daniel.

Comment: I changed the daemon as mongod. I am getting the Error like,                       
Exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating

Comment: I changed the daemon as mongod. I am getting the Error like,                       
**Exception in initAndListen: Illegal Operation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating**.   Can u please suggest me which command we need to use for starting the image automatically?

Comment: _Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db_ is almost certainly an indication that the directory in your PVC is owned by root, and not by the mongo user. You can `chown` it by hand or use an `initContainer:` to `chown` it every time, [as shown by the previous answer I gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51203031/225016)

Comment: Thank you so much Matthew L Daniel. It is worked me for single pod mongodb container.

Comment: I tried with  **3 replicas of mongodb**  through deployment.yml . Only one container is running and remaining two were in  Waiting status. Getting error as  `exception in initAndListen: DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock (Unknown error). Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory, terminating `

Comment: `You can **chown** it by hand or use an init Container: to chown it every time`.  Is it applicable for single mongodb container? Could you please guide me one this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I just now mentally registered the "nfs" portion of your question; reasonable people can differ about whether NFS is appropriate for Mongo, but either way: you'll want to have dedicated PVCs for each member of [the `StatefulSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/); I realize your yaml doesn't say `StatefulSet`, but that is absolutely the construct one should use for databases in-cluster. You can continue to use NFS, it'll just end up being a subdirectory inside the NFS volume for each Pod

Comment: I tried StatefulSets with 3 replicas of mongo containers.I created 3 directories and mapped each one with each pv and pvcs sequentially. 3 pods are in running.How Could i check the data persistency is maintained or not across the cluster?