# postgres on kubernetes volume permission error

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to deploy postgres/postgis on GKE, but I continue to get the permission error: `initdb: could not change permissions of directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data": Operation not permitted`. I've tried various fixes that I've researched but I've yet to get passed this error. Below is my deployment yaml.

What am I missing?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: mdillon/postgis:10
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: "database"
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: "postgres"
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: "postgres"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgredb
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              subPath: data
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pvc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is not exactly the same question, this "use an `initContainer:` to `chmod`" answer will interest you: [chown: changing ownership of '/data/db': Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200115/chown-changing-ownership-of-data-db-operation-not-permitted/51203031#51203031)

Answer (score 3):

The clue can be found under the PGDATA section:

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

> This optional variable can be used to define another location - like a
> subdirectory - for the database files. The default is
> /var/lib/postgresql/data. If the data volume you're using is a
> filesystem mountpoint (like with GCE persistent disks) or remote
> folder that cannot be chowned to the postgres user (like some NFS
> mounts), Postgres initdb recommends a subdirectory be created to
> contain the data.
>
> For example:
>
> $ docker run -d 
> --name some-postgres 
> -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword 
> -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata 
> -v /custom/mount:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
> postgres

So you would need 2 items in the YAML to get the equivalent of the Docker command above:

1. Mount the PVC to the default directory used by Postgres (which you already have in you YAML)

   ```
   volumeMounts:
     - name: <volume_name>
       mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
       readOnly: false
   ```
2. Add PGDATA variable to the env variables:

   ```
   env:
     - name: PGDATA
       value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
   ```