# chown: /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf: Read-only file system

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I solved a permission issue when mounting `/var/lib/postgresql/data` by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200115/chown-changing-ownership-of-data-db-operation-not-permitted/51203031#51203031) with `initContainers`.

Now I'm trying to mount `postgresql.conf` as a volume, and I'm running into a similar permissioning issue that throws `chown: /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf: Read-only file system`.

What could I be missing? I've tried a bunch of different variations with little luck.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  serviceName: postgres
  replicas: 1
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      initContainers:
      - name: chmod-er
        image: busybox:latest
        command:
        - /bin/chown
        - -R
        - '0'
        - /var/lib/postgresql/data
        volumeMounts:
        - name: postgredb
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
        - name: pg-config
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
          subPath: postgresql.conf
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: mdillon/postgis:10-alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgredb
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              subPath: data
            - name: pg-config
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
              subPath: postgresql.conf
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pvc
        - name: pg-config
          configMap:
            name: pg-config
            items:
              - key: postgresql.conf
                path: postgresql.conf
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From kubernetes 1.8 on, configmap is mounted readonly, excerpt from the CHANGELOG-1.8.md:

> Changes secret, configMap, downwardAPI and projected volumes to mount
>   read-only, instead of allowing applications to write data and then
>   reverting it automatically. Until version 1.11, setting the feature
>   gate ReadOnlyAPIDataVolumes=false will preserve the old behavior.
>   (#58720, @joelsmith)

If you want to change the file that mounted from the configmap, you can copy it to another directory, then update it.

Comment: Thanks Kun! Wish I had seen that sooner. You saved me many hours of pain.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately setting `readOnly: false` wasn't enough for my case.

To solve this issue with "Read-only file system" you have to mount your `postgresql.conf` in the directory other than Postgres Data Directory (`/var/lib/postgresql/data` by default)

Try the following:

```
  containers:
    - name: postgres
      image: mdillon/postgis:10-alpine
      args: ['-c', 'config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf']
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: dbdata
          readOnly: false
        - mountPath: /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
          name: pg-server-config
          subPath: postgresql.conf
          readOnly: false
  volumes:
    - name: dbdata
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: dbdata
    - name: pg-server-config
      configMap:
        name: pg-server-configmap
```

Note the `args` section where the custom config is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Update your entity configuration and set readonly to `false`:

```
volumeMounts:
- name: postgredb
  mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
  readOnly: false
- name: pg-config
  mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
  subPath: postgresql.conf
  readOnly: false
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use is to override the postgresql.conf parameters I need as command-line parameters of the container:

```
  containers:
    - name: postgres
      (...) 
      args:
        - -c
        - logging_collector=on
        - -c
        - log_directory=/var/log/postgresql
```

without mounting a modified postgresql.conf

Source: https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#database-configuration