# Kubernetes nginx config read-only file system

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I've created a pod that works as Nginx Proxy. It works well with the default configuration but when I add my custom configuration via ConfigMap it crashes.
This is the only log I have.

> /bin/bash: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf: Read-only file system

My deployment.yaml

```
volumeMounts:
      - name: nginx-config
        mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        subPath: nginx.conf
        readOnly: false
  volumes:
  - name: nginx-config
    configMap:
      name: nginx-config
```

If could help I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884999/chown-var-lib-postgresql-data-postgresql-conf-read-only-file-system) answer on StackOverflow but I don't understand how to do those passages.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your environment, do you mind posting the whole yaml and the nginx.conf? this way I can reproduce it better. also read  [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get a faster and better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config is correct. Reading the Nginx Docker documentation I've found that I have to add `command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "nginx -g 'daemon off;'" ]`