# Traefik: Working with Kubernetes read-only file system

Tags: kubernetes, traefik-ingress

**THE PROBLEM**

I am working on a Django deployment with Kubernetes. The application is working perfectly when run using docker-compose (including automatic TLS certificate generation).

However, when deployed with Kubernetes I run into an issue that seems to be related to Kubernetes read-only file system.

The current state of development is that the Django app is up and running and ingress on the cluster is working (the problem is not related to the Django app).
The problem is that with automatic certificate generation, Kubernetes' read-only file system is preventing acme.json from being modified leaving me with an empty acme.json and without a [certificate](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/acme/) being generated.

The above conclusion is derived form the following: When I check the logs (`kubectl logs pod/traefik-12345 -n stonecap`) I find the following error (see the last line):

```
...
time="2022-02-01T21:11:28Z" level=info msg="Testing certificate renew..." providerName=letsencrypt.acme
time="2022-02-01T21:11:28Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *traefik.Provider {}"
time="2022-02-01T21:11:31Z" level=info msg=Register... providerName=letsencrypt.acme
time="2022-02-01T21:11:31Z" level=error msg="open /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json: read-only file system" providerName=acme
...
```

**RELEVANT FILES**

This is the Traefik controller deployment (the service behind it is irrelevant).

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  namespace: stonecap
  name: traefik
  labels:
    app: traefik
    service: traefik
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: traefik
        image: myrepo/traefik_k8:1.0
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/traefik
            name: all-in-one
        args:
          - --configfile=/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
          - --api
          - --kubernetes
          - --logLevel=INFO
      volumes:
        - name: all-in-one
          projected:
            sources:
            - configMap:
                name: traefik-config
                items:
                  - key: traefik.yml
                    path: traefik.yml
            - configMap:
                name: traefik-acme
                items:
                  - key: acme.json
                    path: acme/acme.json
                    mode: 0600
```

The configmap:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  namespace: stonecap
  name: traefik-config
data:
  traefik.yml: |-
    log:
      level: INFO
    entryPoints:
      web:
        # http
        address: ":80"
      web-secure:
        # https
        address: ":443"
    certificatesResolvers:
      letsencrypt:
        # https://docs.traefik.io/master/https/acme/#lets-encrypt
        acme:
          email: "info@mydopedomain.com"
          storage: /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
          # https://docs.traefik.io/master/https/acme/#httpchallenge
          httpChallenge:
            entryPoint: web
    http:
      routers:
        web-router:
          rule: "Host(`mydopedomain.com`) || Host(`www.mydopedomain.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web
          middlewares:
            - redirect
            - csrf
          service: django
        web-secure-router:
          rule: "Host(`mydopedomain.com`) || Host(`www.mydopedomain.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web-secure
          middlewares:
            - csrf
          service: django
          tls:
            # https://docs.traefik.io/master/routing/routers/#certresolver
            certResolver: letsencrypt
      middlewares:
        redirect:
          # https://docs.traefik.io/master/middlewares/redirectscheme/
          redirectScheme:
            scheme: https
            permanent: true
        csrf:
          headers:
            hostsProxyHeaders: ["X-CSRFToken"]
      services:
        django:
          loadBalancer:
            servers:
              - url: http://django:5000
    providers:
      # https://docs.traefik.io/master/providers/file/
      file:
        filename: /etc/traefik/traefik.yml
        watch: true
```

The acme configmap:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  namespace: stonecap
  name: traefik-acme
data:
  acme.json: ""
```

The traefik Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM traefik:v2.2.11
RUN mkdir -p /etc/traefik/acme \
  && touch /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json \
  && chmod 600 /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
COPY ./compose/production/traefik/traefik.yml /etc/traefik
```

**FIX ATTEMPTS**

I have tried different suggestions without any success.

Per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884999/chown-var-lib-postgresql-data-postgresql-conf-read-only-file-system), adding `readOnly: false` does not help:

```
volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /etc/traefik
    name: all-in-one
    readOnly: false
```

Adding the below, based on this [request](https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/issues/165) ([deprecated](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/)) does not help.

```
securityContext:
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: False
  runAsGroup: 0
  runAsUser: 0
  runAsNonRoot: false
```

The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614034/kubernetes-deployment-read-only-filesystem-error) is not applicable since my case concerns modifying an existing file. In this context I don't believe (feel free to correct me) this can be fixed using an init container ([See issue concerning ConfigMaps](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62099)).

My kubectl version is:

```
$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.21.0
Server Version: v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b
```

**QUESTION**

To reiterate, the problem here is that I am unable to auto generate certificates because Kubernetes is preventing me from modifying a file. Therefore, my question is:

1. What is the (proper) way of modifying a file on Kubernetes' read-only file
   system?
2. How do I fix my specific problem of not being able to modify
   the specified file (referring to configmap traefik-acme)?

Thank you for your time in reading this.

**EDIT**

The cluster was deployed on Amazon [EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/?id=docs_gateway). [eksctl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-eksctl.html) (version 0.80.0) was used to build the cluster. The command used is:

```
eksctl create cluster --version 1.21 --name "$clusterName" --region "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"
```

This deploys 2 nodes by default (Managed nodes – Linux).

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I have added the requested info in the question

Comment: You have mentioned about init containers. Did you try test this solution?

Comment: Have been unable to setup `projected` configmaps with emptyDir. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have some more information? Any errors, logs?

Comment: have you tried placing the mounts somewhere else and using symbolic links? (just an idea i need to test, as I am facing a similar problem)

Comment: @AlexanderMeise, not sure if I have tried this. It has been a while, and I stopped searching for a solution some while ago. The project can be found here though: https://github.com/sitWolf/kubernetes-django-web-app

Answer (score 0):

This approach did also not work for me on Azure Kubernetes Services.

I ended up creating a Storage Class and a Persistent Volume Claim in my cluster. This claim can then be used in the traefik Deployment as volume. Unfortunately, you finally have to upload the two files "traefik-yml" and the empty file "acme/acme.json" into the storage account yourself. It is also worth mentioning that you need to set the 0600 mode in the mountOptions.

Traefik is then able to write into the acme.json file.

Here are the files for you reference:

### Storage Class

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  namespace: release
  name: mvp-aidopt-release-sc
provisioner: file.csi.azure.com
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0600
  - file_mode=0600
  - uid=0
  - gid=0
  - mfsymlinks
  - cache=strict
  - actimeo=30
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
```

### Persistent Volume Claim

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  namespace: release
  name: mvp-aidopt-release-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: mvp-aidopt-release-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

### traefik deployment

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  [...]
spec:
  [...]
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: traefik
        image: traefik:v2.9.4
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/traefik
            name: config-pv
            readOnly: false
      [...]
      volumes:
        - name: config-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mvp-aidopt-release-pvc
```