# MongDB failed to start on OpenShift v3.11 because of failing to read WiredTiger.wt even though the file can be read from Terminal

Tags: mongodb, openshift

I have a MongoDB `StatefulSet` running on OpenShift v3.11. The `PersistentVolume` is using NFSv4.

On our environment, I set up so that the directory in the NFS server are owned by `nfsnobody:nfsnobody`. **SELinux has also been set to Permissive**. All the inner directories and files are also granted with `chmod ug+rwx,o-rwx`.

This is done so that at runtime, when the Pod accesses to the shared path using the user with group `root (gid=0)`, due to NFS by default squashes user and group `root` to `nfsnobody`, the Pod will be able to read and write to the shared path.

```
$> ls -halZ /srv/share/openshift/mongo/
drwxrwx---. nfsnobody nfsnobody unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 data
```

> This set up has been working for months. But then it starts to fail.

However, when I deploy the Pod, it fails to start with the following error:

```
021-01-26T16:12:48.163+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /var/lib/mongodb/data/mongod.lock is not empty.
2021-01-26T16:12:48.163+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb/data created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting theactive storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2021-01-26T16:12:48.163+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2021-01-26T16:12:48.164+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config:create,cache_size=31220M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2021-01-26T16:12:48.688+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1611677568:688148][457:0x7f9b59cc1ca8], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /var/lib/mongodb/data/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operationnot permitted Raw: [1611677568:688148][457:0x7f9b59cc1ca8], file:WiredTiger.wt,connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /var/lib/mongodb/data/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2021-01-26T16:12:48.708+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1611677568:708810][457:0x7f9b59cc1ca8], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /var/lib/mongodb/data/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operationnot permitted Raw: [1611677568:708810][457:0x7f9b59cc1ca8], file:WiredTiger.wt,connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /var/lib/mongodb/data/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2021-01-26T16:12:48.728+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1611677568:728860][457:0x7f9b59cc1ca8], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /var/lib/mongodb/data/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operationnot permitted Raw: [1611677568:728860][457:0x7f9b59cc1ca8], file:WiredTiger.wt,connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /var/lib/mongodb/data/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2021-01-26T16:12:48.744+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
2021-01-26T16:12:48.744+0000 F STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 1: Operation not permitted
2021-01-26T16:12:48.744+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 638
2021-01-26T16:12:48.744+0000 F -        [initandlisten]
```

At first glance, one could say *"it's probably the mongod process does not have the permission to read the file"*. However, when I run in debug mode to access to the Terminal, I can totally access to the path `/var/lib/mongo/data`.

```
$> id
id=1000230000 gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1000230000
$> cd /var/lib/mongodb/data

/var/lib/mongodb/data$> echo "This is a test" >new_file
/var/lib/mongodb/data$> rm new_file
/var/lib/mongodb/data$> cat WiredTiger.wt | wc -l
23
/var/lib/mongodb/data$> mongod --dbpath $(pwd)
....failed...
```

The above commands show that I can read the `/var/lib/mongod/data/WiredTiger.wt` to count the lines but the `mongod` process cannot.

Only if I do

```
# 1000230000 is the random UID and GID granted by OpenShift for the Pod.
$> chown -R 1000230000:nfsnobody /srv/share/openshift/mongo/
```

...the Pod is able to read the files.

Is there anything else I should check to resolve this problem?

*UPDATE*:

- The MongoDB version is 4.0.5.
- Add more log which could pinpoint where the error happened. The [wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r4.0.5/src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp#L638).

Comment: Check permissions for .lock files

Comment: possible question duplication:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200115/chown-changing-ownership-of-data-db-operation-not-permitted

Comment: @Alex Blex the `mongo.lock` has the same permission as `WiredTiger.wt`. Even I delete the `mongo.lock` does not change the outcome, the `mongo.lock` will be created again.

Comment: @R2D2: I checked the other answer and it did not provide solutions that could resolve mine.

Comment: Fair enough, after closer look the error comes from here https://github.com/wiredtiger/wiredtiger/blob/9b32813d625d3dbdf0fd83a7eb4ce10fda0d18f3/src/os_posix/os_fs.c#L662 for the "WiredTiger.wt" itself.

Comment: Hi @AlexBlex, thanks a lot for the link! I managed to track down the [wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r4.0.5/src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp#L638) which I believe the correct impl. But I'm a little bit struggled to explore the code base.

Comment: There is nothing interesting there tbh. It's on the mongo side - it calls wiredtiger_open() 3 times in a row for different version assuming that if there was an error it is because of format of the file. It's why there are 3 consecutive "Operation not permitted" in the logs. The error message itself comes from the `open` syscall. It must be something with openshift permissions. Security layers at https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/install_config/persistent_storage/pod_security_context.html look quite complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the MongoDB source code at the tag [r4.0.5](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/r4.0.5), I can now understand why I got the error.

Thanks to [@Alex Blex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1110423/alex-blex) for hinting the source code!

**Summary**

When `mongod` attempts to read the `WiredTiger.wt` (or any other files), it tries to not update the file's last access time (`st_time` in the inode).  This reason for doing this is [to increase performance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219015/how-to-disable-access-time-settings-in-debian-linux). Under the hood, it uses system call `open()` with a flag `O_NOATIME`.

According to [`open()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> This flag can be employed only if one of the following
> conditions is true:
>
> - The effective UID of the process matches the owner UID
>   of the file.
> - The calling process has the CAP_FOWNER capability in
>   its user namespace and the owner UID of the file has a
>   mapping in the namespace.

The call fails with the error

```
EPERM  The O_NOATIME flag was specified, but the effective user
       ID of the caller did not match the owner of the file and
       the caller was not privileged.
```

In my case, the file is being owned by the `nfsnobody`, not the current UID, hence the error. That explains only by doing `chown $UID:nfsnobody` the problem goes away.

**Some further details**

The error comes from [`posix/os_fs.c`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r4.0.5/src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/os_posix/os_fs.c#L709) when it tries to open a file. At [line 693](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r4.0.5/src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/os_posix/os_fs.c#L693), the flag `NO_ATIME` is set if the `__posix_open_file` is called with `WT_FS_OPEN_FILE_TYPE_DATA`.

Comment: [NFS Volume Security](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_nfs.html#nfs-volume-security) may be of help, and the use of `supplementalGroups` in particular...