# Docker - chown: changing ownership of '/data/db': Operation not permitted

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-volume

I am trying to run my application using Docker and here is my yml file content to run the mongo container.

```
 services:
   mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.4
    #    ports:
    #        - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo:/data/db
    restart: always
```

And getting this error in contianer: (Saw this error after running docker logs command)

> chown: changing ownership of '/data/db': Operation not permitted

The host has ./data/mongo folder and here are the details.

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 nfsnobody nfsnobody 4096 May 11 23:13 mongo
```

I tried to run this on the host as suggested in one of the forums.

```
sudo chgrp 1000 ./data/mongo
```

*Not sure how this would help to solve the issue because the error we get is insdide the container folder not the one from host, anyway i tried.*.

But got this response :

> chgrp: changing group of ‘mongo’: Operation not permitted

How to solve this issue? is there any solution other than "chgrp"? Thank you.

Here is the full docker-compose.yml file

```
## You can generate a custom docker compose file automatically on http://reportportal.io/download (Step 2)

## This is example of Docker Compose for ReportPortal
## Do not forget to configure data volumes for production usage

## Execute 'docker-compose -p reportportal up -d --force-recreate'
## to start all containers in daemon mode
## Where:
##      '-p reportportal' -- specifies container's prefix (project name)
##      '-d' -- enables daemon mode
##      '--force-recreate' -- forces re-recreating of all containers

version: '2'

services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.4
    #    ports:
    #        - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo:/data/db
    restart: always

  registry:
    image: consul:1.0.6
    volumes:
      - ./data/consul:/usr/share/consul/data
#    ports:
#      - "8500:8500"
#      - "8300:8300"
#      - "53:8600/udp"
    command: "agent -server -bootstrap-expect=1 -ui -client 0.0.0.0"
    environment:
      - 'CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"leave_on_terminate": true}'
    restart: always


  uat:
    image: reportportal/service-authorization:4.2.0
    #ports:
    #  - "9999:9999"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - RP_PROFILES=docker
      - RP_SESSION_LIVE=86400 #in seconds
    #      - RP_MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017
    restart: always

  ### Another option for gateway
  ### Can be used instead of traefik
  #  gateway:
  #    image: fabiolb/fabio:1.5.8-go1.10
  #    ports:
  #      - "9998:9998" # GUI/management
  #      - "8080:9999" # HTTP exposed
  #    environment:
  #      - FABIO_REGISTRY_CONSUL_ADDR=registry:8500
  #      - FABIO_REGISTRY_CONSUL_REGISTER_NAME=gateway
  #      - FABIO_PROXY_ADDR=:9999;rt=300s;wt=300s
  #    restart: always



  gateway:
    image: traefik:1.6.6
    ports:
      - "4444:8080" # HTTP exposed
      - "8081:8081" # HTTP Administration exposed
#    expose:
#      - '8080'
    command:
      - --consulcatalog.endpoint=registry:8500
      - --defaultEntryPoints=http
      - --entryPoints=Name:http Address::8080
      - --web
      - --web.address=:8081
    restart: always

  index:
    image: reportportal/service-index:4.2.0
    environment:
      - RP_SERVER_PORT=8080
      - RP_PROXY_CONSUL=true
    depends_on:
      - registry
      - gateway
    restart: always

  api:
    image: reportportal/service-api:4.3.0
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - RP_PROFILES=docker
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp
    #      - RP_MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017
    restart: always

  ui:
    image: reportportal/service-ui:4.3.0
    environment:
      - RP_SERVER.PORT=8080
      - RP_CONSUL.TAGS=urlprefix-/ui opts strip=/ui
      - RP_CONSUL.ADDRESS=registry:8500
    restart: always

  analyzer:
    image: reportportal/service-analyzer:4.3.0
    depends_on:
      - registry
      - gateway
      - elasticsearch
    restart: always

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.1.1
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
  #    ports:
  #        - "9200:9200"

  jira:
    image: reportportal/service-jira:4.0.0
    environment:
      - RP_PROFILES=docker
    #     - RP_MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017
    restart: always

  rally:
    image: reportportal/service-rally:4.3.0
    environment:
      - RP_PROFILES=docker
    #     - RP_MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017
    restart: always
```

Comment: You can give full permission to all users for the directory (if that is safe for your environment) using '''chmod -R a+rwX directory/'''. If it still does not work it would be helpful to share your app structure and whole docker-compose and Dockerfile contents

Comment: @Gray_Rhino , i tried this but have the same issue. Full content of the yml file has been added in the question. thank you..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mongo startup script changes ownership on files in `/data/configdb` and `/data/db` if ran as root. Try running it as `nfsnobody` (the owner of local `./data/mongo`) to skip this step:

```yaml
services:
  mongodb:
    user: "nfsnobody" # insert either uid or name of the user
```

Comment: This helped me solve a similar issue, though I needed to use the username in string form instead of the user ID

Comment: @hampercm both ways are applicable but there is a little difference. If you use name, there must be a user with that name inside the container. With an ID this isn't mandatory.

Comment: Similar to @hampercm I fixed a related problem with a bitcoin docker image, I listed all users and found `bitcoin` user in `/etc/passwd` and added it into docker-compose.yml.

Comment: I got error of: 
Error response from daemon: unable to find user nfsnobody: no matching entries in passwd file

Answer (score 6):

For Mac user running Colima.

I had the same problem on Mac and it turns out it was a problem when using the default Colima settings. Changing the `vmType` to `vz` and `mountType` to `virtiofs`.

To fix this run:

1. `Colima delete`
2. `Colima start --edit` and update `vmType` and `mountType`

Answer (score 5):

I tried to answer here for a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73238863/1294667

In short, we could mount to path `/data` instead of `/data/db`. With this, mongo is able to perform chown on `/data/db` internally.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have user namespace remapping turned on.

Open below file in in your host computer

`/etc/sysconfig/docker`

And Add/Modify these options like below and if required replace root with your user

```
OPTIONS='--userns-remap=root:root'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the volume to a Windows or a Mac host could be limited or hard (see https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/232#issuecomment-355423692). I had similar issues with arm64 Mac and Rancher Desktop, and decided to remove the `volume` but still had issues starting the mongo container.

If you don't really need the shared volume, and just need to resolve the errors, a docker-desktop solution could be:

```
services:
    mongodb:
        container_name: mongodb
        restart: always
        image: mongo
        volumes:
          - mongodata:/data/db
        ports:
          - '27017:27017'

volumes:
  mongodata:
    external: true
```