# How to include security context for running a spark-submit job on kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, security-context

I'm using Spark 2.4.5 to run a spark application on kubernetes through the spark-submit command. The application fails while trying to write outputs as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69972807/chmod-error-while-writing-outputs-with-spark-on-kubernetes), probably due to an issue with an incorrect security context. So I tried setting up a security context and running the application. I did this by creating a pod template as mentioned [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#user-identity), but I haven't been able to validate if the pod template has been set up properly (because I couldn't find proper examples), or if it's accessible from the driver and executor pods (since I couldn't find anything related to the template in the driver or kubernetes logs). This is the content of the pod template I used to set a security context.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: spark-pod-template
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
```

This is the command I used.

```
 <SPARK_PATH>/bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://dssparkcluster-dns-fa326f6a.hcp.southcentralus.azmk8s.io:443 \
 --deploy-mode cluster  --name spark-pi3 --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
 --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=docker.io/datamechanics/spark:2.4.5-hadoop-3.1.0-java-8-scala-2.11-python-3.7-dm14 \
 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.azure-fileshare-pvc.options.claimName=azure-fileshare-pvc \
 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.azure-fileshare-pvc.mount.path=/opt/spark/work-dir \
 --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.azure-fileshare-pvc.options.claimName=azure-fileshare-pvc \
 --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.azure-fileshare-pvc.mount.path=/opt/spark/work-dir \
 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.podTemplateFile=/opt/spark/work-dir/spark_pod_template.yml \
 --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.podTemplateFile=/opt/spark/work-dir/spark_pod_template.yml \
 --verbose /opt/spark/work-dir/wordcount2.py
```

I've placed the pod template file in a persistent volume mounted at /opt/spark/work-dir. The questions I have are:

1. Is the pod template file accessible from the persistent volume?
2. Are the file contents in the appropriate format for setting a runAsUser?
3. Is the pod template functionality supported for Spark 2.4.5? Although it is mentioned in the 2.4.5 [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/running-on-kubernetes.html#user-identity) that security contexts can be implemented using pod templates, there is no pod template section as in the 3.2.0 [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#pod-template).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#pod-template:

> spark.kubernetes.executor.podTemplateFile to point to files accessible to the spark-submit process.

So here, there is nothing about PVC, but local FS where spark-submit is sent. BTW, you can check by inspecting generated pod if this is working.

A good pod & container security-context:

```
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
        runAsGroup: 1000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1000
      containers:
        - name: spark
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            capabilities:
              drop:
              - ALL
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```