# How to set chown in kubernetes deployment persistently?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I'm running a mongodb instance as a kubernetes pod in a single node cluster (bare metal ubuntu machine). The volume is configured `ReadWriteOnce` as the mongodb pod is accessed only by pods in one node.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      hostname: mongo
      volumes:
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: data
        - name: restore
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: restore
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo:4.4.14
          args: ["--auth"]
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data/db
              name: data
            - mountPath: /restore
              name: restore
```

But from time to time I cannot run commands like inserting documents to a non existing collection or running mongodump.
Then I do get the error `MongoServerError: 1: Operation not permitted`. This is caused by a `chown` problem: `ls -ld /data/db/` is returning

```
drwxr-sr-x 4 nobody 4294967294 16384 Jun 28 18:19 /data/db/
```

I can fix the problem by running

```
chown mongodb:mongodb /data/db
```

But after some time it changes again, so the same problem happens again and I have to rerun the `chown mongodb:mongodb /data/db`

I tried to set

```
securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    fsGroup: 2000
```

But then the mongodb pod is failing:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.379+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.383+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.384+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.384+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"mongodb"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.384+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.14","gitVersion":"0b0843af97c3ec9d2c0995152d96d2aad725aab7","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.384+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.384+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*"},"security":{"authorization":"enabled"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-03T10:09:24.386+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

I also tried

```
  initContainers:
    - name: mongodb-init
      image: mongo:4.4.14
      command: ["sh", "-c", "chown 999:999 /data/db"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data/db
```

But after some time I again get:

```
drwxr-sr-x 4 nobody 4294967294 16384 Jun 28 18:19 /data/db/
```

I do not understand what is causing this behaviour.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51203031/5525824

Answer (score 1):

If you set `securityContext` then according to the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod):

> the runAsUser field specifies that for any Containers in the Pod, all processes run with user ID 1000.

there is no fear of mismatching between different processes of the container.

Perhaps you could give (although not recommended) root user access to the pod by setting `runAsUser` to `0`? Just to see if security context can fix the issue. It should.

Comment: I do not understand if `runAsUser` should be `1000` (as often found) or `999` (which is mongodb). And do I have to set `fsGroup` - if yes, which value? Also `999`?

Comment: Yes, it should be uid=999 and groups=999 but I'm wondering if running as root user uid=0,gid=0 will fix the problem, since despite there being a change of ownership, root should be able to write to the volume.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to run `ls -n /data/db` to see what uid has ownership of the directory when it's failing. `nobody` is not useful information.

You set `securityContext` to `1000`, but in the initContainer you set ownership to `999`. That won't work.

What user is the container running as? run `id`.

What user is the mongo process using? There's no assigned user in the Deployment.spec, so I imagine it's a mongoDB config setting. (docs say uid is 999)

Figure out which user id needs to own that directoryissue. Then a possible solution is to mount the path `/data` with the storage provisioner, then create the path `/data/db` with an initcontainer for the mongoDB deployment using the correct uid. That way the directories will have the correct ownership.

Comment: `ls -n` gives me `-rw------- 1 65534 4294967294      47 Nov 12  2021 WiredTiger` for all files. What does that tell me? `65534` is `nobody`. Running `id` inside the mongo container gives me `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`. So `runAsUser` in the securityContext should be `999`? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: It means the directory WiredTiger in `/data/db` is owned by uid `65534`. You can look up a list of users for that system by running cat /etc/passwd but since it's `nobody`, that id isn't going to show up there.  If the container is running as root the container runtime should have access to the directory regardless. __But the mongoDB process might be running as 999__ Your issue is a mismatch between the uid of the mongo process and the ownership of the database.  

Try researching mongo and 65534 and see if that turns up something?